# dc.js : how to wait for complete barchart redraw?

Tags: bar-chart, dc.js, redraw

Hy everybody,

I'm working with dc.js and I think it's a genious tool ! However I have a issue I can't solve.
I'm using a dc.barchart and I want to launch a function of mine after a click on one bar, but I need to wait the end of the redraw of the barchart.

Order :
  - my barchart is displayed
  - I click on one bar
  -> the barchart is redraw
  -> only after the complete redraw, my function is launched

Where can I put my callback ? I can't find the corresponding code.

```
_chart.onClick = function (d) {
        var filter = _chart.keyAccessor()(d);
        dc.events.trigger(function () {
            _chart.filter(filter);
            _chart.redrawGroup();
            alert("here is not working");
        });
};
```

(...)

```
dc.redrawAll = function(group) {
    var charts = dc.chartRegistry.list(group);
    for (var i = 0; i < charts.length; ++i) {
        charts[i].redraw();
    }
    alert("neither here");

    if(dc._renderlet !== null)
        dc._renderlet(group);
};

dc.events.trigger = function(closure, delay) {
    if (!delay){
        closure();
        alert("neither neither here");
        return;
    }

    dc.events.current = closure;

    setTimeout(function() {
        if (closure == dc.events.current)
            closure();
    }, delay);
};
```

Any idea ? I'm completely blocked right now :(
Thanks a lot for your help,
vanessa

Comment: Are the listeners any help? https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/master/web/docs/api-latest.md#listeners

Comment: Yipiii, that seems perfect ! Thank you so much, I didn't know theses functions (I searched however in docs with no success).
Thanks again. Vanessa

Answer (score 1):

If _chart is the name of your chart and you want to execute some function named my_function after finishing drawing, use the following piece of code after the declaration of the chart itself:

```
_chart.on("postRedraw", my_function);
```

Hope this is what you were looking for.